# PyQt5 - TypeError "NoneType" when using *args w/o functools

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt5

I'm getting twice an error while using *args in my maingui (PyQt5) script not sure why. What am i doing not pythonic/pyqt5 style?

First try:

Codeline that gave the error when called from within the GUI:

```
def createActions(self):
    ...
    self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.updateUi('buttons'))
```

The error:

```
Traceback...(snippet)
...
self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.updateUi('buttons'))
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

It might not be a function... so I changed it to my second attemp as Mark Summerfield described in **RapidGUI programming with python and PyQt**, page 133:

```
def createActions(self):
    ...
    self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(functools.partial(self.updateUi, 'buttons'))

 def updateUi(self, *args):

        if args == 'color_update':
            color = self.colorCh2comboBox.currentText()

            if color == 'Violet':
                print '%s is purple' % color
            else:
                print color

        elif args== 'buttons':

            try:
                print 'yes'
                ...
            except:
                print "no"
                ...
        else:
            print "Unknown action : %s" % args
```

> result: "Unknown action : buttons

During the third attempt I've tried:

```
def updateUi(self, *args):

    argument = str(args)   # just to be sure I'll parse a string and not something else.
    ...etc... # as above.
```

What else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did next... checking with `type` what was going on with `args`.

My code:

```
def updateUi(self, *args):

        argument = str(args)
        print type(argument), type(args)
```

Result:

```
<type 'str'> <type 'tuple'>
yes  # from the   try... print 'yes'
no   # from the except.. print 'no'
```

So..args was a tuple (doh!).

Code modified as below and it works now :-)

```
def updateUi(self, *args):

        argument = str(args)
        print type(argument), type(args)

        for item in args:
            if color == 'Violet':
                color = ...etc.
```